# Flask + React + Nginx: pages showing 404 not found for all routes with port number 80

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, web-deployment

I thought I would be able to access react's index page with localhost:80 and apis with localhost/api/example, but am instead seeing a '404 page not found' error for these pages.

However, i am able to render the react's index page with localhost:3000, and the api urls with localhost:5000/api/example.

**nginx.conf**

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    # include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream nodeweb {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    upstream flaskapp {
        server localhost:5000;
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {

            # try_files $uri /index.html; -> adding this line gives 500 Internal Server Error

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            # enable EventSource
            proxy_set_header Connection '';
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_cache off;

            proxy_pass http://nodeweb$is_args$args;

        }

        location ~ /api/(?<section>.*) {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_pass http://flaskapp/$section$is_args$args;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you solved your question? I encountered the same situation as yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding about the setting in nginx.Since you have set proxy_pass ,it's the Reverse Proxy setting.It means listening to 80 port and proxy all the request to proxy_pass,so you can only get response in 3000.

Here are some documents.Hope to help you.http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use uwsgi to handle the request from Nginx. In this way, you can use Nginx to serve your frontend and middleware/backend at the same time.

Do it like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass webmaas-backend:8080;
    }    

}
```